# Creating trigger to compare dates from two tables

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have two tables that both have separate start/end date values in them. One Project can contain many Plans, and a specific Plan start/end date should be between its Project start/end date. I dont know how to validate this, and I have tried to use triggers but I just cant figure it out. Can someone give me some pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

This is my trigger:

```
%%sql
CREATE TRIGGER beforeInsertInPlan BEFORE INSERT ON Plan FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT proID.projectID FROM Project
    INNER JOIN Project ON pID = Project.projectID
    WHERE
```

And here are my two tables:

```
%%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Project;
CREATE TABLE Project (
    projectID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    leader varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    budget varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    startDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31',
    endDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31'
    CHECK (JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate)),
    PRIMARY KEY (projectID)
);
```

and:

```
%%sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plan;
CREATE TABLE Plan (
    pID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    projectID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    startDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    endDate DARE NOT NULL DEFAULT ' '
    CHECK (JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate) AND (startDate >= Project.startDate) AND 
           (endDate <= Project.endDate)),
    PRIMARY KEY (pID, projectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (projectID) REFERENCES Project(projectID)
);
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: @marc_s Im using sqlite, I have a tag for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a BEFORE INSERT trigger will probably result in nothing but issues. see https://sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#cautions_on_the_use_of_before_triggers

So here's a trigger that I believe will work as intended albeit it deleting the inserted row:-

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS afterInsertInPlan 
    AFTER INSERT ON plan 
    WHEN (
            (NOT (new.startdate) BETWEEN 
                (SELECT startdate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID) 
                AND 
                (SELECT enddate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID)
            )
            OR 
            (NOT (new.enddate) BETWEEN 
                (SELECT startdate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID) 
                AND 
                (SELECT enddate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID)
            )
        )
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM plan WHERE pID = new.pID ;
    END
;
```

---

**Testing/Demo**

The above was tested using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Project;
CREATE TABLE Project (
    projectID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    leader varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    budget varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    startDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31',
    endDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-12-31'
    CHECK (JulianDay(startDate) <= JulianDay(endDate)),
    PRIMARY KEY (projectID)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plan;
CREATE TABLE Plan (
    pID varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    projectID varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    startDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ' ,
    endDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
    CHECK (endDate >= startDate),
    PRIMARY KEY (pID, projectID),
    FOREIGN KEY (projectID) REFERENCES Project(projectID)
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trigger_log;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS trigger_log (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, timestamp TEXT DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, trigger_text TEXT);
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS beforeInsertInPlan;
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS afterInsertInPlan 
    AFTER INSERT ON plan 
    WHEN (
            (NOT (new.startdate) BETWEEN 
                (SELECT startdate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID) 
                AND 
                (SELECT enddate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID)
            )
            OR 
            (NOT (new.enddate) BETWEEN 
                (SELECT startdate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID) 
                AND 
                (SELECT enddate FROM project WHERE projectID = new.projectID)
            )
        )
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM plan WHERE pID = new.pID ;
        INSERT INTO trigger_log (trigger_text) VALUES('DELETED FROM Plan Table due to date(s) not within project. pID was '||new.pID);
    END
;

INSERT INTO project  VALUES ('P1','P1','Mary',100,'2021-09-01','2022-09-30');
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P1','P1','Plan1','2021-09-01','2022-09-30');
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P2','P1','Plan2','2021-08-01','2022-09-30'); /* X */
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P3','P1','Plan3','2021-09-01','2022-10-30'); /* X */
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P4','P1','Plan4','2020-09-01','2022-10-30'); /* X */
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P5','P1','Plan5','2021-09-01','2021-10-01');
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P6','P1','Plan6','2021-10-01','2021-11-01');
INSERT INTO plan VALUES ('P1P7','P1','Plan7','2021-11-01','2021-12-01');
SELECT * FROM plan;
/* Cleanup Environment */
SELECT * FROM trigger_log;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trigger_log;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS beforeInsertInPlan;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Plan;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Project;
```

When run then the results are :-

1. The Plan's in the **plan table**:-

[image]

- i.e. those commented with an X (3) were not inserted

2. The trigger_log (used to confirm triggering when testing) :-

[image]

- i.e. the 3 commented with an X that were not inserted have been logged accordingly.

**Example of why not to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger**

Swapping the trigger to use BEFORE INSERT and :-

All are inserted :-

[image]

None are deleted even though logged:-

[image]

- i.e. nothing to delete as nothing has been inserted.

Comment: A BEFORE INSERT trigger (which does not use the NEW.rowid because it is not needed) and a BEFORE UPDATE trigger (which does not update the table), both aborting the operation when the conditions fail is the way to go. Check the duplicate link. Your trigger is awful because it involves several scans of the table and allows unnecessary insertions of rows which will then be deleted.